# How to update iTunes library?

Tags: itunes

I moved my old library into the location on Advanced settings.

Why doesn't it display my music???

EDIT:

OSX 1.7.5

iTunes 11.0.2

It is on my local machine.

Comment: Hi, welcome to AskDifferent.  I need you to clarify more details.  What OS, what version of iTunes etc for a start.  Then people can start to help you in a more targeted way.  If you have any other information, how was it working before, have you moved it to a network location for example, that would also help.  Basically, more details will almost certainly result on either faster or better answers.  At present this question was automatically flagged as low quality, but you can edit it into shape :)

Answer (score 2):

Just moving your music folder to iTunes library directory won't update your library. You need to add to you Library manually by clicking on `File > Add to Library...` and selecting your folder (the one you just moved).
Hope I could help.

Answer (score 1):

So you music files are in your iTunes library's directory? If so then they need to be explicitly added to iTunes. My favorite tool for doing this is [Music Folder Files Not Added](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=musicfolderfilesnotadded2)

Answer (score 1):

You also need to copy the iTunes Library file from ~/Music/iTunes to the new location. That's how iTunes knows what's in the library; it then looks in the location where the music files are to play them.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the answer. Unfortunately I copied it from a PC, and the Library file was in another folder...